# is my translation C code to instructions for CPU correct?

Tags: c, memory-management, instructions, processing-instruction

For this code:

```
int main(void) {
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int* pa = &a;
  *pa = a + b;
  printf("%d", a);
}
```

At compile time the compiler calculates how much space it needs. We have 2 integers and one pointer. So it is `2*4 + 8 = 16`. Then it specifies where the memory of a given variable is in relation to the start point address.
`pa` is at the start point address and have length of 8 bytes.
`b` is at start point address + 8 bytes and have length 4 bytes.
`a` is at start point address + 12 bytes and have length 4 bytes.

Then go instructions for execution time:

1. Ask OS to allocate 16 bytes and provide address for that space in memory. This will be start point address.
2. put the binary representation of `1` at the location of `a`.
3. put the binary representation of `2` at the location of `b`.
4. translate relative address of `a` (start point address + 12 bytes) to its absolute location and put it at location of `pa`.
5. get bytes at location `a` and bytes at location `b`, add them and then get bytes at location `pa`. Use bytes at location `pa` as an address and put there the calculated sum.
6. print the bytes at location `a` converting them to decimal number first.
7. free memory and let the OS know that program finished.

Is this a valid translation?

## edit:

Let's assume a super simple compiler is used (no optimizations). All it cares about is a valid execution of C code.

Comment: It could be. C specifies *what* must happen, but not *how*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I read, yes it is a valid translation. No, it is almost 100 % certainly not the translation your compiler is going to produce. The C standard has the so-called [as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455917/918959) which means the compiler is free to produce *any* program whose side effects are *as if* the program were compiled for the so-called abstract C machine and run in there.

In practice, a compiler could for example produce the following program:

- place the integer `'3'` into the register that is used as the first argument in function calls
- call `putchar`
- zero the register that is used as the return value
- return from the `main` function

To an observer, the side effects of this program would be indistinguishable from those of your program: it prints `3` and returns from `main` with `0` as return value.

Comment: as-if rule and abstract C machine look interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That's pretty much *one* way to translate it<sup>(a)</sup>, although local variables to a function usually get allocated on the stack rather than asking the OS for some amount of memory to store them.

Of course, with a smart compiler, there's enough information in that source code to simply optimise the whole thing down to:

```
int main(void) { putchar('3'); }
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The ISO C standard does not dictate *how* things are done under the covers, only that they behave in certain ways. Think of C as a virtual machine that implements the standard. How the VM does it is not really relevant, and certainly not mandated in any way other than the behaviour.

Comment: argh you even used `putchar` too :/ I am getting bad at FGITW.

Answer (score 1):

*Step 1* The variables `a`, `b` and `pa` will be allocated in the stack. Therefore, there is no request to the OS for memory allocation -- you'll just use the stack, which is controlled by the process itself. Maybe it won't ask for 16 bytes -- 4 bytes are enough, since you're effectively using variable `a`. And even that one is constant, so instances of `a` can be replaced by `1`.

*Step 4:* This step may be completely skipped by the compiler, since you are not using the value of `pa` until it is reassigned in the next step.

*Step 6:* Push the two arguments (`%d\0` string and the value `1`) into the stack and call function named `printf`. No idea if it outputs into a terminal -- maybe `stdout` is redirecting into a file?

In the end it's impossible to know exactly what instructions will be produced from that source code. Depends on the architecture, operating system/OS version, compiler/cc version, compiler flags...